# Cannot run ipython notebook under Enthought Canopy

Tags: path, ipython, enthought

I want to run "ipython notebook" using Enthought Python, but I am unable to do so.

I have set Canopy to be my default Python environment. Using the Canopy command prompt, I can run Python, but not iPython.

```
(Canopy 64bit) C:\>python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:30:12) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:30:12) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\CBrauer.BIGSUR\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Scripts\\python.exe'
>>> quit()

(Canopy 64bit) C:\>
(Canopy 64bit) C:\>ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\CBrauer.BIGSUR\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 9,
in <module> load_entry_point('ipython==1.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
File "C:\Users\CBrauer.BIGSUR\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 345,
in load_entry_point return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "C:\Users\CBrauer.BIGSUR\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 2380,
in l oad_entry_point raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'ipython') not found
```

I have installed Enthought Python on a Windows Server 2012 R2, and my PATH is:

```
(Canopy 64bit) C:\>path
PATH=C:\Users\CBrauer.BIGSUR\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;
S:\SQL Server (x86)\110\Tools\Binn\;
S:\SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
S:\SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;
S:\SQL Server (x86)\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;
S:\SQL Server (x86)\110\DTS\Binn\;
c:\users\cbrauer.bigsur\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;
c:\program files (x86)\dtn\iqfeed;
c:\users\cbrauer.bigsur\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\system\scripts;
c:\users\cbrauer.bigsur\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;
c:\users\cbrauer.bigsur\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user
(Canopy 64bit) C:\>
```

Is this a PATH problem?

Comment: Responding to related ticket off StackOverflow. Looks more like corruption than a PATH problem. However for the record note that ...\canopy\system\scripts should *not* be on the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and was able to solve it by removing ipython and reinstalling it. I used the following commands (enpkg is Enthought's package manager)

```
enpkg --remove ipython
enpkg ipython
```

I believe that in my case I my have corrupted it by doing an ipython update through pip immediately after installing canopy.

Disclaimer: the above worked on a unix system. I overlooked that you are on a windows system. A bit of googling suggests enpkg is also available on windows, but I have no experience there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I'm using Windows XP). After trying a few different things eventually stumbled upon the 'InterruptKernel' option within the Run menu. It seems to have worked and I can now run python scripts with no problems.